# Is there a javascript documentation generator 100% compatible with Google Closure annotations?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, documentation-generation

There are some very similar questions but none of the answers I have found seem to provide a documentation generator that properly supports all google closure annotations. JSDoc does not work properly (at time of writing version 3.3.0 alpha).

JSDoc does works quite well, but cannot handle function types properly like this example:

```
/**
 * @param {function(string)} cbk     A callback taking a string
 */
var hello = function(cbk)
{
    do something...
}
```

The resulting output from JSDoc describes the parameter as type 'function' which is not what I want to see when reading the documentation, I want to see the complete function type with links to dependent documented types.

JSDoc does provide it's own way of documenting callbacks but that way is not compatible with google closure compiler, if you want type checking.

Is there a 100% compatible documentation generator for javascript code using googles closure annotations?

Google guys and girls, if you are reading this, how about releasing your documentation generator used for the closure library? ;)

Answer (score 0):

I just found and tested a very good tool, the best I have tried by far for this task! It supports almost all tags I have used but not @export... so I cannot accept my own answer since the question is about 100% compatibility ;)

I recommend this tool to anyone who have tried JSDoc and was not impressed with it in combination with google closure compiler.
http://www.seehuhn.de/pages/jvjsdoc

The current release has a bug under windows that generated backslash for some URLs. But the fix is simple, just change all usage of `relpath(x, y)` to `relpath(x, y).replace('\\', '/')`